# Is there a workaround for entering fullscreen with keyboard events in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, html5-fullscreen

There seems to be a bug in Edge where you can't enter fullscreen using a keyboard event. Is there a workaround for this?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  // Does nothing in Edge.
  document.getElementById('#container').requestFullscreen();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enter fullscreen using the Enter/Return key only in MS Edge if you use the `keypress` event instead of `keydown`. Other keys will not work. This is a known interoperability issue which we are tracking to fix in a future update.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either. You can see here that changing `keypress` to `click` works fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNxbxY (Edge 20.10240.16384.0).

Comment: Oops, you're right. I looked at our bug more closely and it appears that keypress only works with the Enter key (which is what I happened to be testing with :). No known workaround as far as I can tell unfortunately.

Comment: Look on the bright side; Unlike IE, we're not going to run into "Works okay in IE10, but needs a workaround for IE9 users" issues anymore. I guess it's just up to the Edge team to fix.